# Make a field from a function a url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a function that puts a field into a dd element. One of the fields is a URL.

How do I make it a link?

`<dd class="url">https://www.example.com</dd>`

The function roughly looks like this:

```
$.each([
  'blah',
  'blah',
  'url'
], function(idx, field) {
  searchResultElement.find('.' + field).html(Utils.htmlEntities(result[field]));
});

resultsContainer.append(searchResultElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery method [*wrap*](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/).
So, adding to your function:

```
searchResultElement.find('.' + field).html(Utils.htmlEntities(result[field])).wrap('<a href="' + Utils.htmlEntities(result[field]) + '"></a>');
```

This is assuming that *Utils.htmlEntities(result[field])* is the desired URL.

Or, if you want the  element inside the  element, simply add the code for  in your .html parameter:

`searchResultElement.find('.' + field).html('<a href="' + Utils.htmlEntities(result[field]) + '</a>');`

Answer (score 0):

You can only create proper links using the anchor tag `<a href="LINK">Text</a>`. If you want to use the `dd` element, you can add an `onclick` event listener to all `dd` elements with a certain class. [onclick Example](https://codepen.io/violetlance/pen/wvJdEpq)

Comment: If you're going to provide a code example, you should do it here in your answer as a Stack Snippet, not require people to leave SO and go to codepen. You could keep the codepen _in addition to_ the snippet.